# Can I safely reinstall Daedalus wallet when hardware wallet already exists?

Tags: daedalus

I have a hardware wallet. I have decided to reinstall the Daedalus wallet and link it to my hardware wallet. Does anyone know of a tutorial?

When I reinstall the Daedalus wallet and connect my hardware wallet to my computer, will Daedalus recognize that my hardware wallet had already been set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can re-install Daedalus and re-connect your hardware wallet. As long as you have your seed phrase for the hardware wallet, all is good.

Comment: The "and/or" might be misleading. You **only** and **always** need the hardware wallet recovery seed and your chosen passphrase(s) (if you're using the passphrase feature). Those are the fails safes in case you wipe/lose your hardware wallet or forget the PIN.


Also, you can use the same hardware wallet to recover your Cardano wallets on multiple computers and differnt software wallet programs like Daedalus and Yoroi in parallel.

Comment: Thanks. edited the answer.